# Can you say "don't tell me" in a monologue?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

"Don't tell me" is often used in dialogues, for example "Don't tell me you're tired already!". But can you use it in a monologue? Let's say you have a character in a movie just talking to themselves. Would "don't tell me" be an appropriate substitute for "wait, could it be that he..." or something along these lines? Or does it sound wrong?

Comment: "Aww, don't tell me I've left the oven on again..."

Comment: IMO it's fine as a phrase for personal rhetorical statements. I say it when talking to myself all the time. :)

Comment: @JohnClifford - So do you ever reply to yourself, "I asked you not to tell me that"?

Comment: @HotLicks I usually just get very annoyed with myself for telling myself I left the oven on again and give myself the silent treatment for a while to teach myself a lesson.

Comment: @JohnClifford - Yeah, but silent treatment or no, yourself keeps nagging you for being so stupid, right?

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure you can, people do it all the time. A monologue, doesn't mean you aren't talking to people, it just means no one is talking back (often times because you aren't talking to anyone in particular).

Comment: OK thanks, I was just unsure because in a word-for-word translation to Russian it definitely sounds wrong.